# Assign double variable to mutable array

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I can't figure out why variable `number` is not being assigned to array `self.items`.
In the debugger it is showing value of NULL.

```
-(void)pushItem:(double)number{
    [self.items addObject:[[NSNumber alloc]initWithDouble:number]];

    if (self.items.lastObject == 0)
    {
        // ** need to add variable number to self.items array**
       
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably never initialized your `items` property. Also, your `if` check isn't doing what you probably think it is trying to do. The only way that will ever be true is if `self.items` is nil or if there are no objects in the array.

Comment: FYI - Easier syntax: `[self.items addObject:@(number)];`.

Comment: Did you initialize self.items? Self.items = [NSMutableArray new]; Additionally if you want to check for a number value you should call doubleValue or integerValue on the stored  object

Comment: Is `self.items` nil? `self.items.lastObject == 0` doesn't seems to be the correct way too. Did you meant `if ([self.items.lastObject equalsTo:@(0.0)])` or `if (self.items.lastObject == nil)`? ... ?